# It is easier to iron cotton clothes when slightly wet, why?

Tags: everyday-chemistry, polymers, hydrogen-bond

As the title says, why is it easier to iron cotton clothes when slightly damp ? Has this got something to do with the hydrogen bonding in cotton ?

Comment: cotton is pure cellulose linked by hydrogen bonds. Water inserts into this bonds, allowing shifts between molecules. Water isn't the best grease here, it requires 200+ celsium to have significant and clearly visible effect. Liquid ammonia is much more efficient, allowing to bend thin timber planks.

Comment: It probably steams the clothes a bit more than just the iron by itself.

Comment: @permeakra Water is an excellent plasticisier for all natural fibers. Steaming at 100°C makes even thick wooden beams turn into a soft rubbery material, hardening into any new form during cooling. That's thousands of years of shipbuilding tradition.